# Getting python to type

Tags: python-3.x

How would I get python to type for me. The only thing I've found was on `SendKeys` but I can't find the version for python 3.5. Is there any built in module I can use to get python to type for me?

Comment: What do you mean? How will it get the input and in what sense will it be "typing"?

Comment: I want to run the program, wait 2 or 3 seconds to get to the textbox i want to type in, and then it types whatever for me. Basically simulating a key stroke or multiple key strokes.

Comment: Are you typing in the textbox or is something being automatically entered? I don't understand what you're describing. It's simulating keystrokes but which keys and how does it know?

Comment: I want it to simulate a key press. Where that be typing in a text box or anything else that involves pressing a button on your keyboard

Comment: OK. You want Python to type 'k'. How does it know to type 'k'? I don't know how else to ask this question. The program cannot read your mind to know what to type for you. Where does it get its information about what keypresses to simulate?

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue? If so, please mark it as correct.

Comment: It looks like what i want, but i dont even know where to start to get the package. If you provide me with a link to the download or some sort of instructions, then i will mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `win32api`, assuming windows, has what you need in the `keybd_event()` function. Documentation [here](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32api__keybd_event_meth.html). As for built-ins, not aware of anything like that. Also, see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489149/simulating-a-keypress-in-python).